# Highcharts logarithmic Y-axis exceeding set max

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know this has been asked here a lot and there are already answers to this question both here and in the API Reference. However, none of the solutions have solved my issue.

I am attempting to set the max on the y-axis to 490, but am consistently having it max at 1k. So far I have tried setting the max, setting alignTicks to false, setting the endOnTick to false, setting the tickInterval, and setting the minRange.

```
yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        title: {
            text: 'Amounts'
        },
        max: 490,
        alignTicks: false,
        endOntick: false
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0bj2rjn/)

At this point I'm at a complete loss. My sincere apologies if this has already been answered, I have yet to find any that has worked in this specific instance.

Quick unrelated question: Has anybody made a series span all columns horizontally? Any suggestions on better ways to do this than what I presently have would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: Are you defining your yAxis 'logarithmic' intentionally?

Comment: Its somewhat proportional to series data . when I make it max:400 it works but if I make it 500,490 or else it goes to 1k see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/x0bj2rjn/3/

Comment: Emm... there should be `endOnTick`, not `endOntick` ;) See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x0bj2rjn/4/ Regarding columns, you mean something like [this](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2303560-multi-dimensional-column-charts) ?

Comment: @PawełFus Thanks for the catch! Unfortunately changing this did not help me achieve getting the max to work.

Comment: Could you explain why it doesn't work? I mean, you are missing the last label? In that case use `tickPositioner`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/x0bj2rjn/9/

Comment: @PawełFus Yes! This worked! I didn't know how to use the tickPositioner with an anonymous function. Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept it as one? Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `endOnTick` not `enOntick`. However, setting `endOnTick` to `false` means you will not receive last label/tick (well, just like the name of options says ;) ).

In that case, use `tickPositioner`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/x0bj2rjn/9/

```
    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        title: {
            text: 'Amounts'
        },
        max: 490,
        alignTicks: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
                this.tickPositions.push(max);
            return this.tickPositions;
        }
    },
```